# jQuery add closing tag and then reopen when using .before()

Tags: jquery, html, dom-manipulation

I have this HTML:

```
    <ul>
        <div>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li class="break">c</li>
            <li>d</li>
            <li>f</li>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

What I want is where `class="break"` I want the parent `div` closed and a new one opened so I end up with this:

```
    <ul>
        <div>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
        </div>
        <div>
            <li>c</li>
            <li>d</li>
            <li>f</li>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

Now I've tried this:

`$(".break").before("</div><div>");`

but jQuery doesn't act as I'd expect and instead rewrites what I have entered and puts an empty `div` instead. Like so:

```
    <ul>
        <div>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <div></div>
            <li class="break">c</li>
            <li>d</li>
            <li>f</li>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

So how can I achieve what I am after?

Comment: I don't think `<div>` in `<ul>` is a valid html

Comment: What @andreas said is true, div in ul is not valid. Instead of doing this, what is the final goal you want to reach. Dividing li's in columns?

Comment: The purpose would be to split them into columns. Problem is the menu I've shown is a very simplified menu and the real menu contains many layers.

Comment: If not doable with `div` I'd be happy to accept closing the `</ul>` then reopening `<ul>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you have the following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li class="break">c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>f</li>
</ul>
```

And you want to transform it into:

```
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="break">c</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>f</li>
</ul>
```

You can use [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) with [andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) to get the elements you want to move, then create a new `<ul>` and use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to relocate the elements:

```
var boundary = $("li.break");
$("<ul>").insertAfter(boundary.parent()).append(boundary.nextAll().andSelf());
```

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stLW4/).

Comment: This one saved me, since I couldn't insert a closing tag where I needed it. Thank you!

Comment: Since jQuery 1.8, you should use addBack instead of andSelf.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent Solution

Ok in my case .. lets say i had multiple li.break

so following solution helped me

```
 $("li.break").each(function(){
     var boundary = $(this);
     $("<ul>").insertAfter(boundary.parent()).append(boundary.nextAll().andSelf());
 });
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/stLW4/127/ for more understanding

Comment: Hello sid its amazing but how i can achieve the that li.break is wrap in ul tag and other will work same like you made in js fiddle so it will be actually 3 ul one for a and b other for c and then for d e can i achieve this ?