# How to wrap <tr /> after nth <td> of a table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to wrap <row /> after second td of my table.

Here is my code:

```
<table class="test table">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Row 1 col 1</td><td>Row 1 col 2</td><td>Row 1 col 3</td><td>Row 1 col 4</td></tr>

        <tr><td>Row 2 col 1</td><td>Row 2 col 2</td><td>Row 2 col 3</td><td>Row 2 col 4</td></tr>

        <tr><td>Row 3 col 1</td><td>Row 3 col 2</td><td>Row 3 col 3</td><td>Row 3 col 4</td></tr>

        <tr><td>Row 4 col 1</td><td>Row 4 col 2</td><td>Row 4 col 3</td><td>Row 4 col 4</td></tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to see my code like this:

```
<table class="test table">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Row 1 col 1</td><td>Row 1 col 2</td></tr><tr><td>Row 1 col 3</td><td>Row 1 col 4</td></tr>

        <tr><td>Row 2 col 1</td><td>Row 2 col 2</td></tr><tr><td>Row 2 col 3</td><td>Row 2 col 4</td></tr>

        <tr><td>Row 3 col 1</td><td>Row 3 col 2</td></tr><tr><td>Row 3 col 3</td><td>Row 3 col 4</td></tr>

        <tr><td>Row 4 col 1</td><td>Row 4 col 2</td></tr><tr><td>Row 4 col 3</td><td>Row 4 col 4</td></tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried this way:

```
$(".test tr td:eq(2)").wrap('<tr />');
```

But its not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to loop thru your `<td>`s and wrap it by 2. And using `.html()` update the table `tbody`

```js
$(function() {

  var td = $(".test td");
  var html = "";

  for (var x = 0; x < td.length; x += 2) {
    html += "<tr>";
    html += $(td[x]).prop('outerHTML');
    html += $(td[x + 1]).prop('outerHTML');
    html += "</tr>";
  }

  $(".test tbody").html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="test table">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Row 1 col 1</td><td>Row 1 col 2</td><td>Row 1 col 3</td><td>Row 1 col 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2 col 1</td><td>Row 2 col 2</td><td>Row 2 col 3</td><td>Row 2 col 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3 col 1</td><td>Row 3 col 2</td><td>Row 3 col 3</td><td>Row 3 col 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 4 col 1</td><td>Row 4 col 2</td><td>Row 4 col 3</td><td>Row 4 col 4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

So our final goal is to add `</tr><tr>` after the second `<td>` ends. If you try the code like `$(".test tr td:eq(1)").after('</tr><tr>');`, it won't work. This will add the element like below.

[image]

Because using JQuery you can't add the closing as it as directly like above. You can get more article if you google it for why you can't add closing tag in JQuery. Now coming to our problem, how we can fix the issue.

Thanks to @Frédéric Hamidi giving the solution for the same kind of situation for `ul` and `li` elements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9886743/3607064). In JQuery, you can use [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) with [andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) to get the elements you want to move, then create a new `<tr>` and use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to relocate the elements.  I refactor his solution to fix our issue like below.

```js
$("table.test tr td:nth-child(3)").each(function(){
       $("<tr>").insertAfter($(this).parent())
             .append($(this).nextAll().andSelf());
    });
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="test table">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Row 1 col 1</td><td>Row 1 col 2</td><td>Row 1 col 3</td><td>Row 1 col 4</td></tr>

        <tr><td>Row 2 col 1</td><td>Row 2 col 2</td><td>Row 2 col 3</td><td>Row 2 col 4</td></tr>

        <tr><td>Row 3 col 1</td><td>Row 3 col 2</td><td>Row 3 col 3</td><td>Row 3 col 4</td></tr>

        <tr><td>Row 4 col 1</td><td>Row 4 col 2</td><td>Row 4 col 3</td><td>Row 4 col 4</td></tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/stLW4/219/) is the JSFiddle version, if you want to workout some other stuff.

Comment: Your answer also works. And it is well described. I appreciate.